# Change background color on hover in table with preset background color

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color of my whole tbody using CSS and **:hover**. When a background is already set, I cannot make the hover background change. I simply cannot. I even tried with **!impotant** but without luck.

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Testing</th>
        <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Testing</th>
        <td>Second more stuff</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My CSS**

```
th {
    background: red;
}
tbody:hover {
    background: blue !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4cJh/1/

As you can see, the hover works fine if the background has not been set. Remove the **background: red** from the th-tag, to see that it works without a preset color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `TH` is a child of the table, and so is technically on top of it. By setting the `TABLE` background to blue, it does not override the `TH` background.

To fix this, add this:

```
tbody:hover th {
  background: blue;
}
```

(and you can skip the `!important`s. Those are bad practice.)

[Example fiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/W4cJh/3/)

Comment: If I set the background color of the TABLE to blue, it will still be red.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a bunch - Who would have known that was it? ;)

Comment: Yeah, as you get better with HTML you'll pick up more on how the DOM works. Keep going!

Answer (score 2):

This will do the work for you, no need for `!important`:

```
th {
    background: red;
}
tbody:hover,
tbody:hover th {
    background: blue;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/W4cJh/4/

Comment: @KevinBowersox yes it does.

Comment: Works fine. Same as @dc2's. EDIT: One does not simply tag.